# Accessing value stored in a perl object (blessed hash) from XS

Tags: perl, xs

I have a perl object (blessed reference to hash) like this.

```
sub funcname {
  #some code
}

my $o = My::Class->new();
$o->{internal_data} = \&funcname; #I know it is not nice
```

At other place somewhere in XS code where I have $o reference I need to get the value of `$o->{internal_data}`.

```
/* at some point in XS code */
SV *obj = ... /* $o value passed to a XS function */
SV *func;
...
/* here I do not know how to load $o->{internal_data} value into func */
...
call_sv(func,G_SCALAR);
```

There is perhaps some chapter in perl(api|xstut|guts|???). I just was not able to find it.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

--
kmx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SvRV` will get you the hash (as an `SV*`) from the reference, `MUTABLE_HV` will cast it to a an `HV*`, `hv_fetch`/`hv_fetchs` will fetch from the hash.

```
SV*  self;
SV*  obj_sv;
HV*  obj_hv;
SV** callback_ptr;
SV*  callback;

self = ...;
SvGETMAGIC(self);
if (!SvROK(self))
    croak("Not a reference");

obj_sv = SvRV(self);
if (SvTYPE(obj_sv) != SVt_PVHV)
    croak("Not a reference to a hash");

obj_hv = MUTABLE_HV(obj_sv);

callback_ptr = hv_fetchs(obj_hv, "internal_data", 0);
if (!callback_ptr)
    croak("Malformed object");

callback = *callback_ptr;
```

Comment: @kmx, `MUTABLE_HV(sv)` is basically `(HV*)sv`, except it's safer since it'll issue an error for `const SV* const_sv; MUTABLE_HV(const_sv)`.

Comment: just out of interest: where is this functionality documented? I googled for it, found this tread, but wanted do read the documentation about it also but "MUTABLE_HV" seems not to be documented in perldoc

Comment: It should be in perlapi, but it's not (though it's used in an example). There is a bit of documentation for them in the source where they are [defined](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/572618de69892b6cdf7f9eacce39941a7d3d7ce5:/vutil.h#l8).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "standard" objects, it is underlyingly just a hash, so you can use the HV methods.  See e.g. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Working-with-HVs  (actually, the whole perlguts page would be good reading for this...)

Your SV * to the object is a reference, so you can use SvRV to "dereference" it, casting it to an HV to pass to the hv_xxx functions (e.g. hv_fetch).

Best of luck!